# Makefile for IAR. List of src

Tags: linux, makefile, stm32, iar

I have variable in my Makefile:

```
SRCP = \
 main.c \
 lib1/src/file1.c \
 lib2/src/file2.c
```

Folders `lib1/src` and `lib2/src` may consist other sources, but I need compil only files in `SRCP` var.

I know one variant:

```
OBJ_DIR = ./Release/Obj
OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)
$(OBJ): $(SRCP)
    for source in $(SRCP); do \
        $(CC) $(CLAGS) -c $$source -o $(OBJ_DIR)/$@; \
    done
```

But not informative. In console I see `$source` instead `main.c` (or any name).

My makefile with errors:

```
.PHONY: all clean

PROJECT = hello

IAR_TARGET = ./Release
EXE_DIR = $(IAR_TARGET)/Exe
OBJ_DIR = $(IAR_TARGET)/Obj

COMPILE_OPTS = -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -Wall -g -O0
INCLUDE_DIRS = -I . \
 -I lib/inc

SRCP = \
 main.c \
 lib/src/stm32f10x_tim.c \
 lib/src/stm32f10x_adc.c

LIB = -L ./lib/src

SRC := $(notdir $(SRCP))

OBJ_FILES := $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(notdir $(SRCP:.c=.o)))

CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc
CFLAGS = $(COMPILE_OPTS) $(INCLUDE_DIRS)

# mkdir -p $(EXE_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR)
all: $(EXE_DIR)/$(PROJECT).elf

# Linker invocation
$(EXE_DIR)/$(PROJECT).elf: $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ_FILES) -o $(EXE_DIR)/$(PROJECT).elf

# Rules
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(IAR_TARGET)
```

Error: `make: *** No rule to make target 'Release/Obj/main.o', needed by 'Release/Exe/hello.elf'.  Stop.`

What is the correct version you know?

Comment: Unclear to me. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want to build IAR project in Linux. IAR make *.ewp (like XML). ewp file consist all information about project. I take list of src files. And I dont know how correct write Makefile. My version have not information about current compil source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know!

I have list of files with path:

```
SRCP := \
  main.c \
  lib/src/stm32f10x_tim.c \
  lib/src/stm32f10x_adc.c
```

How to get .c file with path by object name?
Look:

```
OBJ_DIR=Release/Obj
# Rules
%.o:
    @echo creating $@ ...
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(filter %$(subst .o,.c,$@), $(SRCP)) -o $(OBJ_DIR)/$@
```

How to work this `$(filter %$(subst .o,.c,$@), $(SRCP))`?

- For example, **$@** have `stm32f10x_adc.o`
- `$(subst .o,.c,$@)` change .o to .c, so we have `stm32f10x_adc.c`. **Very important!** This string do not have spaces (like I like:) ). I do mistake, when write `$(subst .o, .c, $@)`. It is not clear for me (:
- `%$(subst .o,.c,$@)`. **%** work with filter.
- `$(filter %$(subst .o,.c,$@), $(SRCP))` take `%stm32f10x_adc.c` from $(SRCP) with path. And... We have `lib/src/stm32f10x_adc.c`!

Thankyou for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any specific experience with IAR projects. But I guess I can help you with the Makefile.

The main changes I propose are:

- Change the definition of `OBJ_FILES` such that it contains a list of the object files with the proper path name, e.g. `./Release/Obj/file1.o`. `notdir` removes the directory, `addprefix` adds the new directory.
- Add a pattern rule how to convert a `.c` file into a `.o` file. As object files are a dependency of the final file (a `.elf` file in this example) and as there are no explicit rules to build the these object file, `make` will use the pattern rule to build them.

Most likely, GNU make is required for this makefile.

```
SRCP = \
  main.c \
  lib/src/stm32f10x_tim.c \
  lib/src/stm32f10x_adc.c

OBJ_DIR = ./Release/Obj
OBJ_FILES := $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(notdir $(SRCP:.c=.o)))

# Linker invocation
$(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(PROJECT).elf: $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ_FILES) $(STD_LIBS) -o $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(PROJECT).elf

# Rules
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: ./%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: lib/src/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: Do you mean 
`OBJ_FILES := $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(notdir $(SRCP:.c=.o)))` ?

When execute `%.o: %.c`, how to know path for .c?

I have error:
`make: *** No rule to make target 'Release/Obj/main.o', needed by 'Release/Exe/hello.elf'.  Stop.`

Comment: Yes, OBJ_FILES needs to change as you propose. I somewhat underestimated the problems related to your source file directory structure. I've updated the answer so it uses a separate rule for each source directory.  Hopefully it works; I wasn't able to test it. If not, you might need to use additional Makefiles in the subdirectories with source files.